# 'generator' object is not callable when if inside a for loop in list compression

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am getting the following error when i ran this:

```
df['initial_referrer'].apply(lambda x: value.split("utm_campaign=",1)[1] if 'utm_campaign' in value else np.nan for value in x.split('&'))
```

> TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

I am not sure the meaning of the error and how to modify my this to get rid of this. I have read couple of similar questions here but could not figure our what could be the issue.

So I have values in df['initial_referrer'] be like:

```
df['initial_referrer'].head()
0    /login/index.php
1    /login/index.php?utm_source=INTERNAL&utm_medium=EMAIL&utm_campaign=login-day1
2    /login/index.php
3    /login/index.php?utm_source=INTERNAL&utm_medium=EMAIL&utm_campaign=login-day1
4    /login/index.php
```

And in this, I wanted to extract the value of utm_campaign which is login-day1 thats why I was using the for loop and then if statement it was taking a lot of time/days to process 20mil rows. Therefore I wanted to use generator expression or list compression to process it faster.

Comment: you're not using a list-comprehension, you are using a generator expression

Comment: Basically I was doing this using itterrows earlier but it was taking a lot of time so I thought of doing this using apply

Comment: use itertuples. But `.apply` isn't going to be much faster. It's basically a plain python for-loop underneath the hood

Comment: If you'd extract a [mcve], you might find the error yourself. Also, it would make this question much more valuable to others.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt let me know if question make sense now. I dont think downvote would solve the purpose though but anyways.

Comment: The question still doesn't contain a MCVE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's instructive to first use `apply` with a *regular* function:

```
def func(x):
    return [value.split("utm_campaign=",1)[1] if 'utm_campaign' in value else np.nan \
            for value in x.split('&')]

df['initial_referrer'].apply(func)
```

Notice the square brackets representing the list comprehension. You need to translate this to your `lambda` function:

```
df['initial_referrer'].apply(lambda x: [value.split("utm_campaign=",1)[1] if 'utm_campaign' in value else np.nan for value in x.split('&')])
```

But the latter is unreadable. You are better off writing a regular function.

Note `pd.Series.apply` is a Python-level loop. You can use `map` instead and will likely see a performance improvement:

```
df['initial_referrer'] = list(map(func, df['initial_referrer'].values))
```

Or even a list comprehension:

```
df['initial_referrer'] = [func(x) for x in df['initial_referrer'].values]
```

Comment: Thanks jpp. any particular idea which way would be faster? I have 20mil rows to process

Comment: @Gagan, See my last 2 suggestions. Test them and time to see what's most efficient.

Comment: Thanks @jpp, I changed the function to this: def func(x):
    return [value.split("utm_campaign=",1)[1] for value in x.split('&') if 'utm_campaign' in value][0]

And statement to this: df['initial_referrer_1'] = [func(x) if 'utm_campaign' in x else np.nan for x in df['initial_referrer'].values]. And it worked.